# php array value from data tag to jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get array value from data tag to jQuery but not working.
Here is my code:

```
//$b is taking names from text-area separated by comma.
$a = array_map('trim', explode(",", $b));
return <input type="text" id="pct"><button id="pcthit">submit</button><p id="pct_avail"></p></span>
<input type="hidden" id="storageElement" data-storeIt="'.$a.'">';


$("#pcthit").click(function(){
    var pstcde = $("#pct").val();
    var retrieved_string = [];
    var retrieved_string = $("#storageElement").data('storeit');
    if((pstcde != '') && (jQuery.inArray(pstcde, retrieved_string) >= 0 )){
    $("#pct_avail").html('hello');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to encode the array with `json_encode()`.

```
return '<input type="text" id="pct"><button id="pcthit">submit</button>
        <p id="pct_avail"></p></span>
        <input type="hidden" id="storageElement" data-storeIt=\''.json_encode($a).'\'>';
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I tried with json_encode() but still not working. $("#pct_avail").html(retrieved_string); is giving only bracket "[".

Comment: i replaced all the quotes for input, ( " ) with ( ' ) and ( ' ) with ( " ), now it's working. Thanks a lot for your help :),

Comment: I just changed the quotes around the `data-storeIt` value, since `json_encode()` uses double quotes around all the embedded strings.

Comment: wow, it's a easy way rather than changing all the quotes, thanks :)